# message passing (chrome.runtime.connect()) to extension fails, chrome manifest version 2

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am trying to convert a chrome extension which stopped working in manifest version 2, I have taken out inline javascript, and changed chrome.extension.connect to chrome.runtime.connect, but there still seems to be a problem with chrome.runtime.connect (which i changed from chrome.extension.connect), any ideas?

file ContentScript.js

```
OnDocumentEnd();

var TranslitOn;
var ToggleKeyCode;
var LocalEnabled;
var port;

var ChangeListener = function (event) { OnChange(event); };

var KeyUpListener = function (event) { OnKeyUp(event, event.target); };
var KeyDownListener = function (event) { OnKeyDown(event); };
var KeyPressListener = function (event) { OnKeyPress(event, event.target); };


function OnDocumentEnd() {
    console.log("ode");

    port = chrome.runtime.connect();

    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    console.log("port on msg");
        if (msg.Status != null) {
    console.log("1:"+msg.Status);
   //        TranslitOn = msg.Status;
        }
        if (msg.ToggleKey != null) {
    console.log("2:"+msg.ToggleKey);
           ToggleKeyCode = msg.ToggleKey;
        }
        if (msg.IsEnabled != null) {
    console.log("3:"+msg.IsEnabled);
           LocalEnabled = msg.IsEnabled;
            if (LocalEnabled) {
                Bootstrap();
            }
        }
    });
    port.postMessage({ GetEnabled: true });
    }
```

file translit.js

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/import/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/import/sha1Hash.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/import/ArrayList.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


    if (localStorage.getItem('t_hotkey') == null) {
        localStorage.setItem('t_hotkey', 113);
    }

    var ToggleKeyCode = localStorage.getItem('t_hotkey');


    var TranslitOn = false;

    var GlobalEnabled = true;
    var Ports = new ArrayList();

    function FireOnEvent() {
        try {
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
                chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, { SetStatus: TranslitOn });
                chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, { ToggleKey: ToggleKeyCode });
            });
        } catch (e) { }
    }

    function Toggle() {
        TranslitOn = !TranslitOn;
        FireOnEvent();
    }

    function UpdateToggleKey() {
        FireOnEvent();
    }

    function Save() {
        try {
            localStorage["ToggleKey"] = ToggleKeyCode;
            localStorage["Enabled"] = GlobalEnabled;
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }

function Init() {
    try {
        chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
          port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
            if (msg.GetStatus != null) {
              port.postMessage({ Status: TranslitOn });
            }
            else if (msg.GetToggleKey != null) {
              port.postMessage({ ToggleKey: ToggleKeyCode });
            }
            else if (msg.GetEnabled != null) {
              port.postMessage({ IsEnabled: GlobalEnabled });
            }
          });

          Ports.Add(port);
        });

        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { Toggle();});

        chrome.runtime.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
          try {

            if (request.SetStatus != null) {
              if (request.SetStatus != TranslitOn) {
            Toggle();
              }
            }

            if (request.ToggleStatus != null) {
              Toggle();
            }

            if (request.SetToggleKey != null) {
              ToggleKeyCode = request.SetToggleKey;
              UpdateToggleKey();
            }

            if (request.SetEnabled != null) {
              GlobalEnabled = request.SetEnabled;
            }

          }
          catch (e) { }
        });
    } catch (e) { }
}
```

file manifest.json

```
{
   "background": {
   "scripts":["translit.js"],
   "persistent": false},
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "/import/jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "/code/ContentScript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
   "description": "xxxxxxxxxxt",
   "icons": {
      "128": "img/Icon128.png",
      "32": "img/Icon32.png",
      "48": "img/Icon48.png"
   },
   "key": "MIIBIjAxxxxxxxxB",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "permissions": [ "storage", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "short_name": "xxx",
   "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.23"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You still have HTML code at the top of translit.js. Remove that and add those links to the Javascript files to the background scripts js array in the manifest and you should be good to go:)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was definitely necessary and I've made your helpful mods, but msg properties are still all being returned null, whereas in manifest version 1, they returned values:  port = chrome.runtime.connect();
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        if (msg.Status != null) { .................... and msg.ToggleKey and msg.IsEnabled all returning null